# AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'cv_results_' on scikit-learn 0.19.2

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm currently using Scikit-Learn version 0.19.2 and Python 3.6.3

For some reason, I can't access the `cv_results_` attribute from my `GridSearchCV`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep = ";", header=None)

numpy_array = df.as_matrix()
y=numpy_array[:,1]
y[y=='RR']=1
y[y=='AIRR']=0
print(y)
y=y.astype('int')

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, stop_words=stopwords)

X=numpy_array[:,0]
X=vectorizer.fit_transform(X)

param_grid = {"base_estimator__criterion" : ["gini", "entropy"],
              "base_estimator__splitter" :   ["best", "random"],
              "n_estimators": [1, 2]
             }

DTC = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 11, max_features = "auto", class_weight = "balanced",max_depth = None)


# Create and fit an AdaBoosted decision tree
bdt = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator = DTC)

grid_search_ABC = GridSearchCV(bdt, param_grid=param_grid, scoring = 'roc_auc', cv=5, refit=True)

pred = grid_search_ABC.fit(X,y)

print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y, pred))

mean=grid_search_ABC.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
std=grid_search_ABC.cv_results_['std_test_score']
```

I read that this has mostly to do with `GridSearchCV` not being fitted probably, but I can totally use it to predict new instances and etc.

Any pointers, please?

Comment: So after you `grid_search_ABC.fit(X,y)`, if you do `grid_search_ABC.cv_results_`, is the attribute just not there? And you have `return_train_score=True` or `return_train_score='warn'` so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You are doing this `pred = grid_search_ABC.fit(X,y)`. So pred is actually a GridSearchCV object, not the predictions. Are you sure you are not getting any error in next line: `print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y, pred))`? Post the full stack trace of error.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is probably with your dataset. This is why this sites encourages you to post examples which are verifiable.

I just tried running your code on the iris dataset and it worked just fine:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
iris = datasets.load_iris()
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier

param_grid = {"base_estimator__criterion" : ["gini", "entropy"],
              "base_estimator__splitter" :   ["best", "random"],
              "n_estimators": [1, 2]
             }

DTC = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 11, max_features = "auto", class_weight = "balanced",max_depth = None)
bdt = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator = DTC)
grid_search_ABC = GridSearchCV(bdt, param_grid=param_grid, scoring = 'roc_auc', cv=5, refit=True)

pred = grid_search_ABC.fit(iris.data, iris.target>0)
print(grid_search_ABC.cv_results_['mean_test_score'])
```

and it worked just fine.